# kafka only consume message after specified time

Tags: apache-kafka

I have a kafka topic.

1 month after a message is put onto the topic, I have to take an action.

To do this I'm doing the following in a loop:

1. poll kafka
2. process all messages which were published more than a month ago
3. commit the offset of the latest such message + 1
4. repeat

This doesn't actually work because poll returns messages from wherever it left off, and ignores the commit, unless a rebalance occur.

So I have to buffer unread messages.
But I still have to call poll, as otherwise kafka assumes you've died, and will rebalance. Each poll will return more data.
So that means I'm going to end up storing huge quantities of data in this buffer, which is less than ideal.

What would be ideal would be to tell kafka "I'm still alive", without actually asking for more messages. That way I could loop till the buffer is empty, and only then ask for more messages.

This is what my code looks like:

```scala
  def run(): Unit = {
    properties.setProperty(ConsumerConfig.ENABLE_AUTO_COMMIT_CONFIG, "false")
    properties.setProperty(ConsumerConfig.AUTO_OFFSET_RESET_CONFIG, "earliest")
    val consumer = new KafkaConsumer[Long, Array[Byte]](properties, new LongDeserializer().asInstanceOf[Deserializer[Long]], new ByteArrayDeserializer)
    consumer.subscribe(List(topic).asJava)
    while (true) {
      val pollResult = consumer.poll(Duration.ofSeconds(1))

      val commitMap = for (partition <- pollResult.partitions().asScala) yield {
        val records = pollResult.records(partition).asScala
        val record = records.find(record => {
          if (record.timestamp() + secondsInMonth * 1000 < Instant.now.toEpochMilli) {
            DoAction(record)
            false
          }
          else {
            true
          }
        })
        val offset = new OffsetAndMetadata(record.map(_.offset()).getOrElse(records.last.offset() + 1))
        (partition, offset)
      }

      consumer.commitSync(commitMap.toMap.asJava, Duration.ofSeconds(1))
    }
  }
```

Comment: By default, your messages are gone after 7 days... And you can poll without committing, which would just make it repoll existing data. You can also call `pause` on a consumer to just stop it from polling at all. Might make sense to poll longer than 1 second too

Comment: We're using longer retention here :-). If you poll without committing it carries on after last polled data.

Comment: Okay, well, you don't have to immediately poll within the loop, you can `continue` the loop without a poll, or you can use `ExecutorService` to schedule an actual poll event. Or change the loop condition to be called  in a certain time window.

Comment: But I have to poll within a certain time window, or the broker rebalances. And that will mean that I'll end up storing large quantities of messages in memory.

Comment: As I said, you can pause a consumer, then you don't have to poll and no rebalance after apk consumer threads are paused

Answer (score 0):

You can use `consumer.seek` to make sure that poll continues from where you left off. So the code would be modified to:

```scala
  def run(): Unit = {
    properties.setProperty(ConsumerConfig.ENABLE_AUTO_COMMIT_CONFIG, "false")
    properties.setProperty(ConsumerConfig.AUTO_OFFSET_RESET_CONFIG, "earliest")
    val consumer = new KafkaConsumer[Long, Array[Byte]](properties, new LongDeserializer().asInstanceOf[Deserializer[Long]], new ByteArrayDeserializer)
    consumer.subscribe(List(topic).asJava)
    while (true) {
      val pollResult = consumer.poll(Duration.ofSeconds(1))

      val commitMap = for (partition <- pollResult.partitions().asScala) yield {
        val records = pollResult.records(partition).asScala
        val record = records.find(record => {
          if (record.timestamp() + secondsInMonth * 1000 < Instant.now.toEpochMilli) {
            DoAction(record)
            false
          }
          else {
            true
          }
        })
        val offset = new OffsetAndMetadata(record.map(_.offset()).getOrElse(records.last.offset() + 1))
        consumer.seek(partition, offset)
        (partition, offset)
      }

      consumer.commitSync(commitMap.toMap.asJava, Duration.ofSeconds(1))
    }
  }
```